# Expection of the ratio of two probabiltiy density functions

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions, expectation

If $f$ and $g$ are two probability density functions with same support. Do we have $$\int \frac{f}{g} dx \geq 1? $$

For example, in a discrete case, we have positive numbers $(p_1, \cdots, p_n), (q_1, \cdots, q_n)$ such that
$\sum p_i =\sum q_i = 1.$ Does the following inequality hold?
$$
\sum p_i/q_i \geq n?
$$

If so, how to prove? any counterexample if not?

Comment: Think about this for a little bit: This would imply $\int \frac g f \, dx \ge 1$ as well, by the same reasoning. Does this actually seem reasonable?

Comment: Also, there are counterexamples with $n = 2$....

Comment: What does this have to do with expectation? You are not taking the expectation of the ratio RV you're instead integrating the ratio of two PDFs on their common support.

Comment: Thanks @user296602. you are right...